# CS50 pset5 speller weird bug

Tags: c, cs50

I'm was finished with cs50 pset5 speller(or so I thought), when I ran my complete program for the first time. It started printing out some words, so I was like: "Bingo! I'm done!" and I was seriously happy because I've been working on it for weeks. But then, while it was going through the words, I noticed some words like the word 'and' printed out when they were in the dictionary. So I thought that I had a small bug in my code. But when it came to the end of the list, It didn't do the 'Words misspelled:' Part and the other parts. It didn't even make a new line starting with `$~`. I had to close up that entire terminal because I couldn't do anything else there since it was like this:

```
OUT
THE
END
```

Those words were the last words, and then there's just an empty line. Then I opened a new terminal and checked my answers with the staff's answers, and SO much was wrong! I tried to find some bugs in my code, but I couldn't find any. If you can find some and tell me, I REALLY appreciate it. Here's my code:

```c
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dictionary.h"
#include <strings.h>




// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 19683;
// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{ 
    unsigned int lol = hash(word);
     // TODO
   int i;
   node *cursor =table[lol];;
    while(cursor != NULL)
    {
     
    
      if(strcasecmp(word, cursor -> word) == 0)
      {
          return true;
      }
      cursor = cursor->next;
   
    }
    
    
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int count = 0;
    // TODO
  for(int i = 96; i < 122; i++)
  {
      for(int j = 96; j < 122; j++)
      {
          for(int d = 96; d < 122; d++)
          {
              count++;
              char firstletter = i;
              char secondletter = j;
              char thirdletter = d;
              
              if(word[0] == firstletter&& word[1] == secondletter && word[2] == thirdletter)
              {
                  
                  return count;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  return 1;
    
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Open dictionary and check for memory issue
    // Open dictionary file and create word array
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Check for memory issue with dict
    if(dict == NULL)
    {
        printf("Dictionary is null\n");
        unload();
        return false;
    }

    // Read string 1 word at a time
    while (fscanf(dict, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        strcpy(n -> word, word);
      

        // Index word using hash function
        int dict_index = hash(word);

        // Insert into hash table if already empty
        if (table[dict_index] == NULL)
        {
            n -> next = NULL;
        }
        // Insert work as new node if not empyty
        else
        {
            n -> next = table[dict_index];
        }

        table[dict_index] = n;

    }

    // Close dictionary file
    fclose(dict);

    // Indicate success
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
   int count = 0;
   
    // TODO
     for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {   
 
       while(table[i] != NULL)
       {
         node* cursor = table[i];
            count++;
         cursor = cursor -> next;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{

    // TODO
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
    node *cursor = table[i];
    while(cursor)
    {
        node *temp = cursor;
        cursor = cursor -> next;
        if(temp != NULL)
        {
            return true;
        }
        free(temp);
    }
    }
  
return 1;
    
}
```

Thanks a lot,
Lost in code.

Comment: So I should do free at the end of the load function?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the code. I thought it was a linked list, but it seems to be a chained hash table or such.

Comment: It's ok, it happens to the best of us.

Comment: So anyway, where's the calling code? This is already a whole lot of code, but I think the problem might be with how you call the functions. It would be helpful if you could narrow it down to the part you suspect might be wrong.

Comment: I could narrow it down, But the problem is I suspect the bugs are spread out so I have to show the whole code in case I don't show a part with a bug

Comment: Unrelated, that if-else logic in your chain setup is pointless. Just use `n->next = table[dict_index]; table[dict_index] = n;` . Think about the value of `table[dict_index]` in both the no-previous-entry and previous-entry cases and you'll understand why. More important, however, in the `size` function, `while(table[i] != NULL) { count++; }` Um... when exactly will that while-condition *ever* change ?

Comment: I changed my code, now the while condition will change. But for the first part of your advice, could you tell me which function you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `hash` is not case sensitive. Any word in the text with a capital letter will go in index 1.
- `unload` has an infinte loop here `while(table[i] != NULL)` because `table[i]` never changes

Fixing these two issues should produce progress, though maybe not total success.

NB ctrl-c *should* end a program that is stuck in a loop without needing to close the terminal.

Comment: I fixed the unload, but thanks for the hash tip. I'll try it, and tell you if it works

Comment: Ok, I tried what you said, and it stopped outputting words like 'the' Which are in the dictionary but are capital, but it STILL just ends when it reaches the end of the list and doestn't do the "Words Misspelled" part. Here's my unload code: `bool unload(void)
{

    // TODO
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
    node *cursor = table[i];
    while(cursor)
    {
        node *temp = cursor;
        cursor = cursor -> next;
        if(temp == NULL)
        {
            return true;
        }
        free(temp);
    }
    }
  
return 1;
    
}
`

Comment: And here's my hash code: `unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int count = 0;
  for(int i = 96; i < 122; i++)
  { for(int j = 96; j < 122; j++)
      {for(int d = 96; d < 122; d++)
          {
              count++;
              const char firstletter = i;
              const char secondletter = j;
              const char thirdletter = d;
              if(strcasecmp(&word[0], &firstletter) == 0 && strcasecmp(&word[2], &secondletter) == 0 && strcasecmp(&word[3], &thirdletter) == 0){
                  return count;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  return 1;
}
`

Comment: same bug in size that was fixed in unload. Suggest counting words as they are added to the linked list and returning that value in size. Traversing the list adds  unnecessary time.

Comment: But I add words to the linked list in hash, so how do I take a value from hash and return it in size?

Comment: A global variable that is incremented every time a word is added to the linked list (in `load`)?